# Can an Account object have a lookup to another Account?

Tags: lightning, account, many-to-many

I need a way for the Account object to track Partners (which should also be an Account record). In a traditional relational database I'd model this by making a many-to-many relationship with a "Partners" table in between.

Is there a way to do this in Salesforce? Essentially an Account record can be just that, an Account, but I'd also like to link it to other Accounts (as Partner).

I thought of using Contacts for this but it isn't appropriate for this scenario because the contact should technically be able to have other partners not necessarily related to the original partner.

I've also considered making a custom "Partner" object so I can add one or many partner(s) to the Account. But then I don't have a way to treat those Partners as Accounts if they go off to do other transactions separately. I suppose I could do this and trigger a flow to create an Account from that Partner entry and add the original Account as a partner as well. This seems unnecessarily complicated.

I'm new to Salesforce, so wondering if there is a better way to handle this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a [Partners](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_partner.htm) object in Salesforce, and it works exactly as you've described; a related list (junction object) between Accounts and even Opportunities. You can customize the Partners object in Setup, and add it to your page layout. You can read more about [adding Partners](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.partners_edit.htm&type=5) in the documentation.

Comment: amazing, thanks!